# While searching a string with Prisma I am getting this error "'mode' does not exist in type 'StringFilter<"Post">"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I am trying to implement Search feature in my Next.js / Prisma project.

Here's the schema of the Post model:

```
model Post {
  id          Int            @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  title       String         @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  slug        String         @unique @db.VarChar(150)
  description String         @db.VarChar(10000)
  author      User           @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId    Int
  createdAt   DateTime       @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime       @updatedAt
  reports     Report[]
  archived    Boolean?       @default(false)

  @@index([title])
  @@index([authorId])
  @@index([slug])
}
```

And this is how I am searching for the posts:

```
    const posts = await prismadb.post.findMany({
      where: {
        archived: false,
        title: {
            contains: searchString,
            mode: 'insensitive',
        }
      },
```

But the 'mode' is giving an error:

```
Type '{ contains: string; mode: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | StringFilter<"Post"> | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'mode' does not exist in type 'StringFilter<"Post">'.
```

What's wrong here? The title is of string type so it should not be a problem.